# Problem with suggested solution to Searching People in Photos 3.0 and 4.0

Tags: photos

I have created a Smart Album as suggested in a post dated Dec 30, 2018. However it does not work.
It brings back thousands of photos which are clearly tagged with the persons name and they do show up in the relevant People album. Any other ideas how to locate photos with unidentified people in them?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and how Dawn. What search terms did you enter and what results did you hope to show? Perhaps if you add screen shots of what precisely you did we might be able to help other than to suggest you talk this out with someone who can see your screen shoulder to shoulder.